# How to Pivot a grouped by table

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table that looks like this

```
myDate    myClass    myCount
1 Jan 17  A1         70
1 Jan 17  B2         60
1 Jan 17  C3         90
2 Jan 17  A1         50
2 Jan 17  B2         80
3 Jan 17  A1         20
3 Jan 17  C3         10
```

that I have got through this query

```
SELECT myDate, myClass, Count(*)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY myDate, myClass
```

I want to Pivot the table to look like this

```
myDate    A1   B2   C3
1 Jan 17  70   60   90
2 Jan 17  50   80   0
3 Jan 17  20   0    10
```

I can do it by something like this

```
SELECT myDate, 
SUM(CASE myClass WHEN 'A1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A1,
SUM(CASE myClass WHEN 'B2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B2,
SUM(CASE myClass WHEN 'C3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS C3
FROM myTable
GROUP BY myDate
```

but myClass could have new Classes and not limited to 3 classes only it can grow to 200 classes.

Comment: With `MSSQL` there is no direct way to produce dynamic numbers of columns without using a `prepare` + `execute` statement. Have you consider building the `SELECT` as a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` variable and then use `EXEC sp_executesql @statement` ?

Comment: @JonathanLarouche dynamic SQL is my plan B

Comment: Do you know how to start? I can provide some sample code

Comment: @JonathanLarouche thanks, I have already done that, just hoping for an easier way

Comment: Fastest way is generating the query using `STUFF` and `FOR XML` concats, I will post a sample anyway

Comment: In my solution, i've changed a little bit the CASE WHEN SUM to not return a COUNT of record but the Actual SUM. In your question the working SELECT was returning COUNTs but your expected result is showing SUMs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `generic` solution that will generate a `Dynamic sql` statement and will return the `SUM` of records `PARTITIONED` by `GROUP BY` Fields

SQL goes as follow:

```
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = CONCAT (
        N'SELECT myDate, ',
        (
            SELECT STUFF((
                SELECT CONCAT (
                        N',SUM(CASE WHEN [myClass] = ''',
                        myClass,
                        N''' THEN myCount ELSE 0 END) AS [',
                        myClass,
                        N']'
                        )
                FROM myTable
                GROUP BY myClass
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '')
            ),
        N'FROM myTable GROUP BY myDate'
        )

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```