# Add columns to query result

Tags: sql-server, pivot, pivot-table, ssms-2014

```
DECLARE @strPivotColumns NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT 
    @strPivotColumns = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + item 
                              FROM table 
                              WHERE id = '9972' 
                              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM
    table 
GROUP BY
    item

 SELECT DISTINCT    
     column1,
      .....
     column10,                  
     @strPivotColumns                   
FROM        
    table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    table2 ON table2.id = table1.id
```

Original result of above query

```
column1|column2|@strPivotColumns column I want to change
abc    |   def |    y,z,x....N
```

Result I am expecting

```
column1|column2|Address1|.......|AddressN|
abc    |    def|   y    |.......|   N    |
```

I spent lot of time looking for pivot examples, and went through many examples, didn't find a case that suits my scenario.

Comment: Gave an answer few months ago about something similar : [how-to-pivot-a-grouped-by-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58176878/how-to-pivot-a-grouped-by-table/58177433#58177433). Does it help?

Comment: thanks for reply @JonathanLarouche it didn't help, in my case i need to iterate through a comma seperated values

Comment: What could be the values of the ITEM column in your table? Can you add sample of @strPivotColumns

Comment: its a string of addresses, for "strPivotColumns" i may get N number of addresses -@JonathanLarouche

Comment: How do you distinguish address1 vs address2 etc.. does the addresses have a poisiton/index? Does a record could have a infinite or finite number of addresses?

Comment: "strPivotColumns" variable can have zero to N number of addresses and i only get addresses in to that variable-@JonathanLarouche

Comment: How/By what this result will be used? Why having a column at the end containing the text separated by "," is not good enough?

Comment: add it to xml element and display, due to other issues in code, i need to handle this in sql itself -@JonathanLarouche